# How to add unit to a number in SASS

Tags: css, sass

I would like to know how I can add a unit to a certain number of a variable in [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/):

```
$number: 10;
padding: $number / 2 & px;
```

the `&` does not work. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
padding: $number / 2 + px;
```

Googled your question => result [this site](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/sass/correctly-adding-unit-number/)

Comment: from the same linked page: "While this method works, it is far from ideal because it results in implicitly casting the initial value as a string (…) To work around this issue, there are two ways of doing this properly: $value: 42; $length: $value + 0px; (…)"